# Unable to build gradle project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I am not able to build my gradle project. I have installed gradle in my saystem and building it through command promt. , getting this below error.
[image]

Error : **Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.**

My build.gradle is  :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
   compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server')
   testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
}

mainClassName = 'server.Main'

allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  
  dependencies {
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        
  }
  sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
  targetCompatibility = '1.8'
  
  dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR5'
    }
  }
  
    task deletelogs(type: Delete) {
      delete 'logs', 'bin', '.settings', '.classpath', '.project'
      followSymlinks = true
     
    }
    
    task deleteBin(type: Delete) { 
        delete 'bin'
        followSymlinks = true;
    }
    
    task deleteBuild(type: Delete) { 
        delete 'build'
        followSymlinks = true;
    }
    
    task deleteLogs(type: Delete){ 
        delete 'logs'
        followSymlinks = true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone let me know what can be the issue? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like gradle cannot connect to that repository or cannot find log4j in that repository.

You can try adding another repository to download log4j (or any other dependencies) from.

Comment: Its not able to download any dependency.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot as your repository? I see you used mavenCentral for the buildscript repository. Maybe you can also use mavenCentral as the root repository.

Answer (score 0):

Add `mavenCentral()` in the second `repositories` block, so that it becomes:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
}
```

Else it will look for all your libs in the spring snapshots, which won't work.